# Understanding an example of a finitely generated projective module which is not free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, direct-product, free-modules

Here is the example I know:

Consider the ring $R = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ and the submodule $\mathbb Z_2 \times \{0\}.$ it is by construction a direct summand of $R$ but certainly not free.And it's finitely generated.

But I do not understand:

1- how $\mathbb Z_2 \times \{0\}$ is a direct summand of $R$ by construction?

2- Why $\mathbb Z_2 \times \{0\}$ is not free?

Any clarification is very much appreciated.

I know that it is finitely generated because it is generated by $\{(0,0) , (1,0)\}.$

Comment: A nonzero free module is isomorphic to at least one copy of $R$, which has four elements. The submodule has two elements.. how many copies of $R$ do you expect to fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a direct summand, because for abelian groups $G \oplus H \simeq G \times H$ and the module structure is the same as the group structure.

It's not free, because there is a non-trivial relation $r \cdot (1,0) = (0,0)$, which is the zero element of $R$.  In this case, $r = (0,1)$.  That's the definition of free: Since $\lbrace (1,0), (0,1) \rbrace$, which we denote by $\lbrace e_1, e_2 \rbrace$ for clarity, is a basis for $R$ as a module, the relation $r_1 \cdot e_1 + r_2 \cdot e_2 = 0$ implies $r_1 = r_2 = 0$ if $R$ is free.  But we just showed that this isn't the case.

Comment: Was the elements that I said it was finitely generated by them correct?

Comment: why for abelian groups the module structure is the same as the group structure?